# RxJava - Emit items like in a queue

Tags: java, android, queue, buffer, rx-java

I have an observable that:

- emits data after few seconds.
- can be triggered several times.
- the operation can't be executed in parallel. So we need a buffer.

I understand that this isn't clear so let me explain with example:

```
Observable<IPing> pingObservable = Observable.defer(() -> 
                         new PingCommand(account, folders)
                             .post()
                             .asObservable()
                     );
```

this is the main feature. It shouldn't be called again while a previous one is executing, but it should remember that user requests it again. So I created close buffer as `PublishSubject`

```
closeBuffer = PublishSubject.create();
```

now I'm wondering how to merge it.

I have tried this:

```
Observable.defer(() -> new PingCommand(account, folders)
            .post()
            .asObservable()
            .buffer(() -> closeBuffer)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .first()
);
```

but it is not working as I want.

Edit: 
I will try to explain that better:

I'm sending POST to the server - We can wait for a response several MINUTES (because it is Exchange ActiveSync PUSH). I cannot ping again while one request is sending. So I have to wait until one request is done. I don't need to buffer those observables - just information if an user is requesting ping - and send request after a first one is done. I'm just learning reactive so I don't know how to really use complicated functions like backpressure.

This is how I want this problem to be solved (pseudo code)

```
??????<Result> request
        = ????.???()
        .doOnNext( result -> { … })
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> { … })
        .doOnCompleted(() -> { … })
        .…
        //__________________________________________________________

        Observable<Result> doAsyncWork(Data data) { … } // this is API function
        //__________________________________________________________
        // api usage example

        Subscription s1 = doAsyncWork(someData).subscribe() // start observing async work; executed doOnSubscribe
        Subscription s2 = doAsyncWork(someData).subscribe() // wait for async work result …
        //__________________________________________________________

        // after some time pass, maybe from other thread
        Subscription s1 = doAsyncWork(someData).subscribe() // wait for async work result …
        //__________________________________________________________

        // async work completes, all subscribers obtain the same result; executed doOnCompleted
        //__________________________________________________________

        // again
        Subscription s1 = doAsyncWork(someData).subscribe() // start observing async work; executed doOnSubscribe


        // async work completes, subscriber obtains result; executed doOnCompleted
```

Obviously, I can use `if` instead but I want to know how to do it in a proper way.

Comment: So, you want to execute one task at a time but if multiple events come in, they should be coulde? What about backpressure? How much would you like to buffer?

Comment: need more precise description of desired behavior

Comment: Have you looked at `replay()`?